# ASIC/FPGA hardwares to compute Scrypt hashes

Tags: hash, scrypt, gpu

[this](http://alpha-t.net) company claim Scrypt mining by ASIC (on crypto [currencies](http://www.coindesk.com/scrypt-miners-cryptocurrency-arms-race/) who use scrypt hashing as proof of work)

scrypt is made to keep ASIC/FPGA attackers away, is that claim expired?

Comment: At the current moment in time, it's impossible to scrypt hash using only claims.

Answer (score 0):

scrypt is designed to be *expensive* to implement in hardware because of the memory requirement. Technically it's possible to create an ASIC that will compute scrypt hashes, but such a device would require very large amounts of RAM and would be cost-prohibitive to produce.